# Как получить доступ к node.js приложению, завернутому в docker-compose?

Tags: node.js, nginx, docker, proxy, docker-compose

Пробую организовать инфраструктуру приложения с docker-compose.
Вот исходный код:

server.js

```
const fastify = require('fastify');

const app = fastify();
const port =  3333;

app.get('/', (_req, res) => {
    res.send('Hello world!');
});

app.listen(port, (error) => {
    if (error) {
        console.error(error);
        process.exit(1);
    }
    console.info(`fastify server listening...`);
});
```

Dockerfile:

```
FROM node:12-alpine
RUN mkdir -p /node_app
WORKDIR /node_app
COPY . .
EXPOSE 3333
RUN npm i --quiet
```

docker-compose.yml:

```
version: '3.2'

services:      
  mysql:
    ...

  adminer:
    ...
    ports:
      - 8080:8080

  node1:
    build: ./node
    container_name: node1
    hostname: node1
    command: npm run start
    volumes:
      - ./node:/node_app/
    ports:
      - 3333:3333
      - 9229:9229
```

запускаю `docker-compose up` и вижу

```
node1        | fastify server listening...
```

но при запросе из браузера на `http://localhost:3333/` получаю 404.
При этом на порту 8080 нормально открывается adminer.

Пробовал добавить в инфраструктуру nginx:

```
webserver:
    image: nginx:mainline-alpine
    container_name: webserver
    restart: unless-stopped
    ports:
      - 80:80
    volumes:
      - ./nginx-conf:/etc/nginx/conf.d
    depends_on:
      - node1
```

с таким конфигом:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    listen [::]:80;

    root /var/www/html;
    index index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html;

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://localhost:3333;
    }
}
```

и в браузере обращался уже на 80 порт, но все что поменялось, это ответ 404 был стилизован nginx'ом.

Как мне скорректировать конфиги чтобы иметь возможность обратиться к ноде извне?

Answer (score 0):

Проблема оказалась в fastify который по умолчанию слушает только localhost.
Поправил инициализацию сервера на

```
app.listen({port: 3333, host: '0.0.0.0'}, (error) => {...
```

и все взлетело.

Теперь вот разбираюсь как это грамотно спрятать за nginx.